# Why is overflow-hidden ignored if a child element is set with absolute positioning?

Tags: html, css

#### Overflow hidden is ignored if the following are implemented:

- An overflowing child element has absolute positioning
- The parent with overflow hidden has static positioning
- A second parent wrapper with relative positioning is added

Why is it that this occurs despite the parent having overflow hidden applied?

[image]

---

**HTML**

```
<div class="outer-wrapper">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="overflowed">(Overflowing the wrapper)</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.outer-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.overflowed {
  position: absolute;
}
```

**FIDDLE**
http://jsfiddle.net/vLsmmrz6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because the absolute positioned div `.overflowd` stays relative to the `.outer-wrapper`, not to the `wrapper`. So what's happening it's not overflow but it's normal behavior.

If you have an element with `position:absolute` which has an ancestor or more with `position:relative` , it will stay absolute relative to the closest ancestor with `position:relative`

For example, in the snippet below. i added another wrapper. If i set position:relative to that wrapper, it won't matter, because a closer ancestor of the absolute div has position:relative.

If you remove the position:relative from `outer-wrapper` and keep position:relative on the  new wrapper `.more-wrapper` , the absolute div will move and stay absolute relative to the `more-wrapper`

Hope i explained clearly

```css
.outer-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  padding: 100px;
  background: white;
}
.more-wrapper {
  position:relative;
  background:red;
  padding:100px;
}
.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 200px;
  background: darkblue;
}
.overflowed {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  background: lightblue;
  padding: 50px;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="more-wrapper">


<div class="outer-wrapper">
  <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="overflowed">(Overflowing the wrapper)</div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Just found your answer with a simple google search. You can read more here > [css position](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)

> An element with position: absolute; is positioned relative to the nearest positioned ancestor (instead of positioned relative to the viewport, like fixed).
>
> However; if an absolute positioned element has no positioned ancestors, it uses the document body, and moves along with page scrolling.
>
> Note: A "positioned" element is one whose position is anything except static.

Comment: In other words... http://jsfiddle.net/vLsmmrz6/3/